# prefixing string to SQL group by values

Tags: sql, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a basic query that illustrates a more complex example:

```
select   country, sum(revenue)
from     world_tbl
group by country
```

This would return results such as

```
Canada | 500
USA    | 700
```

I would like to add a string value of 'cntry_' as a prefix to the country for an operation so I don't have to perform this outside the DB.  How would I go about doing this?

Desired:

```
cntry_canada | 500 
cntry_usa    | 700
```

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Appending a static string to the `country` column should work

`ANSI SQL` standard.

```
select   'cntry_' || country, sum(revenue)
from     world_tbl
group by country
```

Some of the `RDBMS` supports `Concat` function

```
select   Concat('cntry_' , country), sum(revenue)
from     world_tbl
group by country
```

Some `RDBMS` supports `+`

```
select   'cntry_' + country, sum(revenue)
from     world_tbl
group by country
```

Comment: "SQL" (the standard query language) uses `||` for string concatenation. `+` is for numbers